# Batch File: `Do call :Process`

Tags: batch-file, process

In a batch file, how should I change `@for /L %%i in (0,1,9) Do call :Process 950%%i` Which originally opened sequentially `9500.lnk`, `9501.lnk`, `9502.lnk`, `9503.lnk`, `9504.lnk`, `9505.lnk`, `9506.lnk`, `9507.lnk`, `9508.lnk`, & `9509.lnk`

When I have changed each of the shortcut names and added something after the four numbers? Because now that I added something different on each one after those four numbers(to make the console windows more easily recognizable on the taskbar), Window can't find those shortcut files.

This is for auto-starting Halcyon Regions.

Here is the `Autostart.bat` file.

```
@Echo Off
: System Autostart of regions
C:
@Echo Starting up Grid services!

cd \Users\Administrator\Desktop\HalcyonGridIcons
start "Whip Assets 1" "Whip Assets 1.lnk"
timeout 40
start "Grid Users 2" "Grid Users 2.lnk"
timeout 3
start "Grid Server 3" "Grid Server 3.lnk"
timeout 3
start "Grid Messaging 4" "Grid Messaging 4.lnk"
timeout 3

@Echo Starting up regions!
start "Grid Aperture 5" "Grid Aperture 5.lnk"
timeout 3
@for /L %%i in (0,1,9) Do call :Process 950%%i

goto Done

:Process
echo Checking port %1
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\RegionChk.ps1 %1
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto Done
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto Skip
start "%1" "%1.lnk"    ((Actually, this line might have to be changed?))
timeout 15
:Skip

:Done
: Send email to notify of startup.
 start "Sendmail" "C:\Sendmail.lnk"
```

It runs all five Grid Services fine, but since I changed the shortcut names for the regions, Windows Can't find `9500.lnk`, `9501.lnk` et cetera.

The new shortcut file names are the same with only the region name appended after the number, as in: `950* region name.lnk`

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe an example of what the new file names are would help us better understand how to change your code.  Would help to see what the `:Process` function is doing as well. Please read [mcve].

Comment: `950%%i*` ? is single character, * is 0 or more characters.

Comment: I would think something like this would work assuming the LNK files are in the same directory: `for /L %%i in (0,1,9) Do FOR %%G IN (950%%i*.lnk) DO call :Process "%%G"`

Comment: Why has your question got a GitHub project page link? At first I expected it to contain the missing content of your `region.ps1` file, but unless its buried somewhere deep within its project tree, I could not see it! My assumption is that you're passing the port numbers as an argument to that powershell script, which is performing a task using that argument and returning a string and/or an error code. Can you please confirm whether that assumption is correct, and if it is, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65782731/edit) to include its content, so that we can test the code.

Comment: @Compo Forget about the GitHub link then, was just for reference in case some people don't know what Halcyon Grid is.& the `C:\RegionChk.ps1` is just a check on the website.

Comment: @Squashman Do you mean that to replace `@for /L %%i in (0,1,9) Do call :Process 950%%i` ?  Because if you did, it doesn't work.

Comment: Look again at the second and third comment.

Comment: @life777eternal, I can't debug based off "it doesn't work".   First two rules of debugging a batch file. 1) Don't use `@ECHO OFF`. 2) Open up a command prompt and execute the batch file from the cmd prompt instead of using your mouse. Using the base logic of your code it works just fine for me.

Comment: @Squashman Forget it, I had to change the shortcut lnk names back to just the port numbers. The website controls won't function if they're named anything in addition to the port numbers. Thanks for the comments and answer, it may or may not work. And I may delete this question soon. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Checking port %1
SET "region950="
for %%r in (%1*.lnk) do ECHO found %%r&set "region950=%%r"
REM AT this point, %region950% contains the link filename
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\RegionChk.ps1 %1
```

Well, I have no idea whether you need to fit `%1` (containing, eg. 9503) or the link filename as `%region950%` into the remainder of your code. You should be careful to use quotes `"as necessary since your names appear contain spaces"`